# Use colors with artist-mode

Tags: colors, artist-mode

Is there a good robust method to draw with colors in artist-mode or a similar mode?  By this I mean setting the foreground and background faces to colors such as red, green, blue, etc. for individual "pixels" (characters) when drawing with the mouse or programmatically.

I've concluded it's not supported out of the box as the only notion of "color" in artist.el corresponds to character weight (`M` is "darker" than `-`) and there is no mention of faces.  Since artist-mode relies on characters rather than strings (`artist-fill-char-set`, `artist-line-char`, etc.), the user can't propertize with a face.

My experiments adding face properties to inserted characters (in `artist-replace-char` and `artist-replace-chars`) are somewhat successful.  Before I dig into fixing the hygiene of inserted character faces I want to check be sure that I'm not duplicating existing work!